# Observable and Retrofit handle big data retrieving

Tags: android, rx-java, reactive-programming, observable, retrofit2

I've ever used retrofit and observable together but never faced with big data problems.

The problem is: When you've got some api that is returning a huge amount of data, in a Json array for example, which one is the best way to display object in a RecyclerView for example?

What i have in my mind is, that i should push the single object of the json list into the observable.onNetx() once i've got it.
So instead of waiting for the all list to be loaded, just whenever we've got an object fully loaded and ready, we push it into the UI.

Tell me what do you think about it and if this is doable having a Json array or if the implementation should come directly from the api instead.

Thanks

Comment: `returning a huge amount of data, in a Json array` sounds like a bad idea. Why not do the pagination?

Comment: Okay, and what would be an implementazion of a REST pagination on the client side with the observable pattern?